# get_template_part inside get_posts()

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im trying to show a list of posts including their Title & Image on a post. Im using the `get_posts()` function with an array to filter the posts. I know that `$template_loader->get_template_part( 'content-listing-image');` get the post image, but when I use it on the output it shows me the image of the current post, not the filtered ones (`$evento`)

This is my code:

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'author'         => $post->post_author,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'   => '_listing_type',
            'value' => 'event'
        )
    )
);

    $eventos = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ( $eventos as $evento ) {
        $template_loader = new Listeo_Core_Template_Loader;

        $output .= '<div><a href="'.get_permalink( $evento->ID ).'" target="_blank"> '.$template_loader->get_template_part( 'content-listing-image').' '.$evento->post_title.'</a></div>';  
    }

    if(!empty($eventos)) : ?> 
        <div id="listing-eventosartista" class="listing-section">
            <h3 class="listing-desc-headline margin-top-60 margin-bottom-30"><?php esc_html_e('Eventos','listeo_core'); ?></h3>
                <div class="single-item">
                    <?php echo $output; ?>
                </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

I want to show the corresponding image to each `$evento` (post).

Hope yoy can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get_the_post_thumbnail(), like this

```
$output .= 'ID ).'" target="_blank"> '.get_the_post_thumbnail( $evento->ID).' '.$evento->post_title.'';
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the image associated to this type of post is not getted by that function. It doesn't show me anything. I think that i need to adapt somehow the `$template_loader->get_template_part( 'content-listing-image');` on the `$output`

Comment: Use get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())

Comment: Thanks! with that it shows me the thumbnail of the actual post, not the `$evento` image, any suggestion?

Comment: You can print $envato array, so that you can check complete array

Comment: Like `get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID($evento))` ?

Comment: No, like print_r($envato);

Comment: Thank you, now it works, it was just another problem..The `$evento` posts did not have a featured image.. My bad. get_the_post_thumbnail($evento->ID) worked!